Linqpad 8 can't connect to .NET 8 SQL Server DbContext
I get an error trying to add a connection in LinqPad 8.4.11. I want to use the dbContext from a .NET 8 dll. The only choice I have is the constructor for DbContextOptions (connection string omitted):

which results in an error:

Error Testing Custom EF Core Connection: A named connection string was used, but the name 'sqlConnection' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information.

The context is injected with this code:
public static void ConfigureSqlContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) => 
    services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(opts => 
        opts.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"))
);

The appsettings.json has the sqlConnection.

LINQPad does not know about your ConfigureSqlContext method, so it's not going to be able to pull a connection string from your IConfiguration. This is why you must specify the full connection string in the box provided.
Specifying a connection string is generally beneficial because it allows LINQPad connections to point to any database. If you prefer to use the connection string defined in your appsettings.json file, you can do so by defining a parameterless constructor - click the 'Help me choose' link for info on how to do this.
